Memory issues in kafka
During Kafka's work, we noticed that the Garbage Collector was freeing up less and less memory.
memory leak
We are using a kafka cluster with three brokers with the following settings:
POD_NAME: metadata.name POD_NAMESPACE: metadata.namespace KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3 KAFKA_DEFAULT_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 3 KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS: -Xmx3g -Xms1g KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: **.*.**.***:2181 KAFKA_LOG_DIRS: /opt/kafka/data/logs KAFKA_CONFLUENT_SUPPORT_METRICS_ENABLE: false KAFKA_JMX_PORT: 5555 KAFKA_JMX_OPTS: -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS: -server -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=20 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=8m -XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent -XX:MaxInlineLevel=15 -XX:G1MixedGCCountTarget=4 -XX:G1ReservePercent=20 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=5 -XX:TargetSurvivorRatio=80 -Djava.awt.headless=true KAFKA_JMX_HOSTNAME: status.podIP KAFKA_MESSAGE_MAX_BYTES: 15728640 KAFKA_MAX_REQUEST_SIZE: 15728640 KAFKA_REPLICA_FETCH_MAX_BYTES: 15728640 KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_PROTOCOL_VERSION: 2.8-IV1 KAFKA_LOG_MESSAGE_FORMAT_VERSION: 2.8-IV1 KAFKA_LOG_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000 KAFKA_LOG_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MESSAGES: 20000
We use: JDK 11, confluentinc/cp-kafka:6.2.13, Memory Request 4Gi, Memory Limit 4Gi.
We changed the Garbage Collector parameters MaxGCPauseMillis, InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent, G1HeapRegionSize, but did not achieve any improvements.
In the Kafka broker settings, we set the following parameters KAFKA_LOG_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS and KAFKA_LOG_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MESSAGES.
On queues with the delete policy, we changed the cleaning settings such as retention.ms.
On queues with the compact policy, we changed the settings max.compaction.lg.ms, min.cleanable.dirty.ratio, delete.retention.ms.
But we did not get any results.
We expect that the Garbage Collector should work as follows:
expected result
We want to get rid of such memory leaks:
we want to get rid of


can you get a heap dump? 2) Kafka documentation says linkedin uses 6gb max heap 3) Confluent supports Java 17 now, so you could upgrade and use Z1GC


@OneCricketeer 1) yes, we can, should I send it to you? 2) in the production environment we have a value of 40gb and the memory still leaks over time 3) there is no way to upgrade to JDK 17 yet
